# How to Play video file from my own application in jsp(File is in my own server Mysql database.)

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, video-streaming

Can any one help me,About how to play video file in jsp application.Where the video file exist in my own mysql databse (BLOB format).Can any one suggest how to play thoes video file in jap page(streaming).

1.is there any API to play video file like. you tube Embed code.or viemo player..

2.is there any server side configuration settings..

Regard
Sourav nandan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easiest is HTML5, these days. Try reading [this](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html) to see what you need to do. You will also need to provide a servlet which will dump your BLOB into its response stream.

Another way would be Flash - there are plenty of solutions for that, for instance [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/). (You still need that servlet, though.)

Comment: thanx amadan.

we are able to download the video file from database . but the problem is player is not able to fetch the video file..we are using jquery pretty photo to show video.

Comment: As far as I can see, prettyPhoto supports MOV and FLV. Are you using one of these formats? And are you setting the correct MimeType? (`video/quicktime` and `video/x-flv`, respectively)?

Answer (score 0):

[HTML5 Video Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp)

I don't know about jQuery, but AFAIK, you need [jQuery Media Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/media/) to play videos using jQuery.